# Using different minimal complete definitions for different datatype constructors

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I have a typeclass `Transforming`, with two complete definitions `apply` and `fill`.  Here it is:

```
import Data.Set (Set, foldr, union, empty, map, singleton)
import Prelude hiding (foldr, map)

class Transforming t where
  apply :: (Ord a) => t a -> a -> Set a
  apply trans = fill trans . singleton
  fill  :: (Ord a) => t a -> Set a -> Set a
  fill trans = foldr union empty . map (apply trans)
```

*(The exact specifics are more or less unimportant to the question, but I thought I would include them)*

Now the way I have it set up to infer member functions is nice, but often naive. So if I am making an instance of `Transforming` I may want to implement either `apply` or `fill` depending on what is most efficient, and let Haskell handle the other. (Or in rare cases implement both)  And this is fine that is kind of the point of having a typeclass.  However at this point I would like to make a new datatype as follows

```
data SimpleTransform a = SingletonTrans (a -> a) | GenericTrans (a -> Set a)
```

Now when making this `SimpleTransform` an instance of `Transforming` I want to implement `fill` for instances constructed with `SingletonTrans` and implement `apply` for instances constructed with `GenericTrans`.  I would like to write something like this:

```
instance Transforming Transform where
  fill (SingletonTrans f) = map f
  apply (GenericTrans f) = f
```

However this doesn't work. Since `Transform` is a single datatype I need to completely define one of the two minimal definitions rather than partially define both.  Now there are ways around this problem.  The simplest is to just fully define both instances, however this is a super simple example and as the number of complete definitions in my typeclass grows and the number of constructors grows this begins to require repeating lots of code.

Is there a way I could use different complete definitions for different constructors of the same datatype?  Is there some way I ought to restructure my code in order to make this unnecessary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another way, using `Data.Functor.Sum`

```
newtype SingletonTrans' a = SingletonTrans' (a -> a)
instance Transforming SingletonTrans' where
  fill (SingletonTrans' f) = map f

newtype GenericTrans' a = GenericTrans' (a -> Set a)
instance Transforming GenericTrans' where
  apply (GenericTrans' g) = g

instance (Transforming f, Transforming g) => Transforming (Sum f g) where
  fill (InL f) = fill f
  fill (InR g) = fill g
  apply (InL f) = apply f
  apply (InR g) = apply g

type SimpleTransform = Sum SingletonTrans' GenericTrans'
```

You can even use `PatternSynonyms` to make `SimpleTransform` act just like the original definition:

```
pattern SingletonTrans :: (a -> a) -> SimpleTransform a
pattern SingletonTrans f = InL (SingletonTrans' f)

pattern GenericTrans :: (a -> Set a) -> SimpleTransform a
pattern GenericTrans g = InR (GenericTrans' g)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  And thanks for introducing me to both `Data.Functor.Sum`, and `PatternSynonyms`, both are really interesting.  I ended up using this solution so I am marking this as accepted. Lastly I just thought I would point out that you are missing an `s` in `Tranforming g`.

Answer (score 5):

Here is one way:

```
applyDef trans = fill trans . singleton
fillDef trans = foldr union empty . map (apply trans)

class Transforming t where
  apply :: (Ord a) => t a -> a -> Set a
  apply = applyDef
  fill  :: (Ord a) => t a -> Set a -> Set a
  fill = fillDef

instance Transforming Transform where
  fill (SingletonTrans f) = map f
  fill trans = fillDef trans
  apply (GenericTrans f) = f
  apply trans = applyDef trans
```